# Is there a command to factory reset Ubuntu?

Tags: reset

I have a black screen on my PC, and I've somehow got in the terminal
the terminal is all black and I can only do commands.

Is there a command to factory reset your PC through the terminal?

Comment: This blog talks about a software which can reset Ubuntu to factory default I have not tried, but definitely worth a peek http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/reset-ubuntu-desktop-default-settings

Comment: Looks like you are encountering the xy problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem
Isn't your main problem the black screen? If yes then you should ask about how to fix the black screen, because you might find very simple (maybe just 1 command) answers.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Try configuring unconfigured packages:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   ```
2. Update the contents of the repositories

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Try to fix missing dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```
4. Update all packages with new versions available:

   ```
   sudo apt-get full-upgrade
   ```
5. Reinstall Ubuntu desktop:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
   ```
6. Remove unnecessary packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
7. Delete downloaded packages already installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get clean
   ```
8. Reboot the system to see if the issue was resolved:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

Comment: everyone is saying that there is no way to reset. then what does these commands do?

Comment: @WaseemAhmadNaeem: Restore system and graphical environment to initial configuration (factory reset  PC thru the terminal)

Comment: why use exec sudo -i, just sudo -i enough @kyodake

Comment: @solfish:  exec   replace the shell with the  program executed, not as new process.

Comment: +1 works if < dconf reset -f / > gives : "Error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY with error : "

Comment: does this work well with aws boxes ?

Comment: None of them work: The following packages have unmet dependencies:

Answer (score 19):

There is no such thing as factory reset in ubuntu. You have to run a live disk/usb drive of any linux distro and backup your data and then reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: Finally, a direct and honest CLEAR answer: NO. Period.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this only re-installing from bootable USB stick worked as the above verified answer didn't work for me.

Answer (score 15):

You can use :

```
dconf reset -f /
```

Running this command will reset, among other things: the apps pinned to the Unity launcher or Ubuntu Dock ; panel applets and/or indicators; monitor resolution and interface scaling; keyboard shortcuts; fonts, GTK and icon theme; window button placement, launcher behaviour; and so on.

This command will also reset any application that uses dconf to store its settings. This includes core desktop apps like Rhythmbox, Evince, Shotwell and Nautilus.

This latter point is important to keep in mind as this command may reset library settings, delete accounts, disable plugins, and/or require you to re-authenticate with online services.

On the flip it means this command is the perfect one to run when you want to reset GNOME 3 settings.

Comment: doesn't work, won't affect packages