# wifi dose not show any networks

Tags: wireless

i ran into a problem where i my ubuntu to the background image then stops luckily i had the crosser working . after solving this issue by using (sudo apt-get install compizconfig-setting-manager) i found that my wifi dose not show any networks although it is enabled i found a solution to it by the command 
(sudo systemctl restart network-manager) but it needs to be done every time i restart the machine

Answer (score 0):

I installed some network mangers such as http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing and http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing and done a bunch of installs and removes such as http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing then i rebooted and it now works . i tried also this answer but it didn't work https://askubuntu.com/a/859463/793268 long story short i tried a lot of things hopelessly and was not expecting to see a change but it happened .