# Hidden (missing) indicator-keylock icon

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, indicator

I am using indicator-keylock on Xubuntu 18.04 (both on my desktop and laptop). I accidentally hid the icon and now I can't find a way to bring it back. The pop up notifications still work, but I'd like to have a persistent icon so I can check 'numlock' without toggling the key.

I've tried removing the program (`apt remove`,`apt purge`,`apt autoremove`, etc), but after re-installing, the same behavior persists. Is a configuration file that can be changed? If so, where is it (typically) located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04.3 and I found this:

After a couple hours looking for some config file or something, I looked on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023071/reset-application-to-its-default-state). **Edit**: So indicator-keylock config files **could be** somewhere there, but you can't go and open them. To do this easily, you want to install **dconf-editor**

Open the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type `sudo apt install dconf-editor` Then open it (you can do this from the installed apps menu) and go to /apps/indicators/keylock and select every option (at least this is what I did)

Reboot your system and the icon will be again in the top menu.

English is not my mother tongue so I hope you can understand it!

Comment: I looked in the .config folder and didn't see it. Do you happen to remember the name of the config file?

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. After installing dconf-editor, I was able to find the settings for indicator-keylock immediately.

Comment: Edited my reply so another users could go to dconf-editor directly, instead of searching config files

Comment: Looks great! Instead of rebooting, I just restarted my panel and restarted indicator-keylock.