# Ubuntu GNOME 20.04 screen/mouse keeps freezing/stuttering

Tags: nvidia, gnome, xorg, screen, 20.04

Ubuntu GNOME 20.04, i7 6700, gtx 1660s, recently set to UEFI, 2-3 monitors (2 and a tv across the room for videos), proprietary nvidia driver.

For no reason I can find, my screen freezes for about .1 seconds at roughly 1 second intervals, regularly (Literally precise as clockwork). It is most noticeable with a mouse, since it makes it really jerky, but exists for video, windows, typing, etc. Audio is smooth, anything non-graphical is smooth, mouse movements are smooth under it but look jerky due to freezing.

Still exists with no windows open, still exists unplugging/disabling other monitors, still exists swapping to noveau. top shows xorg using ~20-30% cpu, system monitor app shows 3-5%.
System monitor extension is not installed going by gnome tweaks menu, I've heard of similar issues with it. I've been messing with boot stuff recently (putting ubuntu server on a 1,1 mac pro, which is...hard), but changed nothing I can think of in this install.

Comment: Could be related to this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1872796

Comment: I'm having the same problem. None of the current solutions worked. Everything was working fine until I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You could give nvidia-xconfig a try: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/nvidia-xconfig.1.html

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem by applying the solution described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/996151/1092682). Just for the record:

```
dconf reset -f /
```

After that, the stuttering was gone. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: looks like shooting a nuclear bomb against a mosquito :-D the problem here is that we do not know  what is the mosquito like

Comment: It worked for me, but like @lrkwz said, it is a bomb to kill a mosquito... all my settings and visual styles were reverted back as my first installation (wallpaper, menus, font size, terminal etc,.. but the mouse works again, so, worth it.

Comment: Yeah. I never figured it out either, literally ended up doing a clean reinstall. Sorry I never came back with an answer

Answer (score 2):

https://dragoshmocrii.com/ubuntu-20-04-stuttering-animations-video/

Stuttering for my system was caused by the `indicator-multiload` extension.

Enter this command on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove indicator-multiload
```

Comment: if change "System monitor update interval" for example to 1000 ms, in indicator-multiload- freezing gone

Answer (score 2):

NVIDIA Driver is the problem. You will have to rollback each time. I think 330 works.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem on Ubuntu 20.04.

I just tried to disable memory swapping and it's gone.

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

To make it persistent, comment swap in `/etc/fstab`.