# Dual Boot Ubuntu 20.04 does not detect highest resolution which is available on Windows 10

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, display-resolution

I am running a 2-monitor dual-boot system using Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10, equipped with an NVIDIA RTX 2070 (driver version 450.80.02).

On Windows, the maximum resolution of my larger monitor is correctly identified as 2560x1440.

Windows Image Resolution:

[image: Windows_img_resolution]

But on Ubuntu, the maximum resolution of this monitor is set to 2048x1080 or 1920x1080. This monitor is connected to the video card using an Amazon Basics HDMI cable which states it is able to support 4K resolution.

Is it possible to create custom resolutions for this monitor (like I did to unlock the highest resolution on Windows using the NVIDIA Settings there)?

I already tried the following ways:

- Create `xorg.conf` file using NVIDIA X Server Settings (both adding Modeline from CVT and Modes line (SubSection "Display") did not work).
- `xrandr --addmode` failed with error code 45

  [image: img_error]
- the `Xorg -configure` command fails with "Number of created screens does not match the number of detected ..."

Comment: After booting from a Ubuntu 20.04 USB stick, the full resolution (2560x1440) is shown. Is there a way to override all resolution customizations in my current installation or is a full reinstallation necessary for that?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the resolution is available using stock-settings of Ubuntu 20.04 in my local setup.

Therefore, I tried to reset the configuration of X-server (deleted `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` which I previously configured in various ways and also deleted `.config/monitors.xml`.

After both of these steps did not show any effect and the desired resolution was still not available, I resetted all software on my system ([See this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859448/is-there-a-command-to-factory-reset-ubuntu)).

This affected the available resolutions: Only one monitor was available, showing 640x480 pixels. Then, I used `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to bring a fresh install of the nvidia display drivers to my system.

After a reboot, the monitor instanteneously detects the full resolution of 2560x1440 pixels.