# reset pulseaudio to default permanently

Tags: pulseaudio

I bought some wireless earphones that didn't pair with ubuntu and I found this tutorial https://atish3604.medium.com/solved-bluetooth-headset-mic-not-working-detected-in-ubuntu-20-04-86a5236444d0 that would help do that, it kinda worked but not in the way I hoped so I want to revert to how it was before so he recommends using these commands

```
systemctl --user unmask pulseaudio
systemctl --user --now enable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
```

works perfectly except it's temporary and whenever i restart ubuntu i have to type them again, i want to make it permanent, i tried creating a new account hoping it was account specific changes but no its system wide.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution was to reset ubuntu to factory settings

[Is there a command to factory reset Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859448/is-there-a-command-to-factory-reset-ubuntu)